# What could cause an Angular app to hang when using the DOM explorer in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I have an angular app that works fine on every other browser, but on internet explorer when I open the development console and try to use the DOM explorer, areas where components should be rendered are showing empty spaces, although the site has actually loaded them.

If I wait around 10 seconds the empty spaces in the DOM explorer get populated but then opening a nested component in the DOM explorer causes the same problem.

There are no errors in the console, nothing of interest in the network tab.

Since there is literally no code to show I can only ask if anyone has seen this before and what might be a likely cause for this?

EDIT: eventually the site crashes

Comment: are you using svg file anywhere?

Comment: yes I am. And some console.logs but I cant get the dom explorer open in time to see them run

Comment: removed svgs - same issue

Comment: I narrowed the problem down to the sass loader - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139826/why-is-my-angular-apps-ie-compatible-css-grid-sass-implementation-causing-ie-to